# Scaling images in Android not working like supposed to

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse, imageview

I have a long vertical image (224x1600). I want it to fit the image width, and scroll vertically. It needs to be scroll-able. I have tried everything and can't get it to work :\

Here is what I have

```
<ScrollView
                xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

                <LinearLayout
                    android1:id="@+id/tab3"
                    android1:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android1:layout_height="fill_parent" >

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                        android:src="@drawable/tiles" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </ScrollView>
```

Second question is: Is there a way to PREVENT image scaling? The image is 224x1632 and shows that way on my galaxy nexus. On the Nexus 7 (much larger screen but lower DP) it goes to 199x1440. A weird scaling of 88%. Can I prevent this? I need it to display 224x1632 on all machines and scale the width accordingly.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to avoid scaling entirely, you should place your drawables in the `res/drawable-nodpi` folder. Keep in mind that the physical size will be much different on devices of different densities, but as long as you understand the risks, that is the solution you should pursue.

On your first question, I'm inclined to think you'll need to do some manual work in code, but although I can't test it right now, this also might work:

```
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:src="@drawable/tiles"
        />
</ScrollView>
```

Give it a shot and let me know how it goes.

Answer (score 0):

It should work... I think the problem is that you have `android1:` and it is suppose to be `android:`

Something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/tab3"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <ImageView
           android:id="@+id/imageView1"
           android:layout_width="fill_parent"
           android:layout_height="fill_parent"
           android:src="@drawable/tiles" />

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

As for the second question, you can try and use `android:minWidth=""` and `android:minHeight=""` to see if that solves your problem.

**EDIT:** try `android:scaleType="fitCenter"` it will display the image as is.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Changed it to android: and still nothing. Also, minimum width would differ per device. So that wouldn't work... in XML anyway

Comment: Strange, the code that I posted works for me. Can you post your main activity class, maybe that is were the problem is. Or your image is not loaded properly. Make sure you clean your project then close and reopen Eclipse (if your are using Eclipse).

Comment: In regards to the other question you could try `android:scaleType="fitCenter"` I will update my answer.

Comment: It might have to do with the fact that I am using a tab widget

Comment: Maybe it has to do with my tab widget?

Comment: Well in that case, post all your xml code so we can see what is causing a problem.  Also you can take out that part of your code and just try what I have posted and see.

Comment: You should change all `android1:` to `android:` also the error that you are getting is a known bug, take a look at: [TabWidget](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=13092)

Comment: hmm changed it all but doesn't do much. the error... i don't get an error. maybe warnings. project runs but the image appears thin taking up 25% of the screen or so and long... doesn't fill width